# common packages between Bioconductor and CRAN

Tags: r, package, bioconductor, cran

Is there any package which is submitted in both Bioconductor and CRAN repositories? Can a package be submitted in both repositories? How can we realize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your penultimate inquisition, it is generally (IMO) bad form to cross-submit since bioconductor has a very narrow focus & CRAN has a much larger focus and will pull from bioconductor if necessary. Those more familiar with bioconductor should correct said opinion if it is errant, though (generally not a problem with SO R folks these days, civility component of said corrections notwithstanding).

Answering your initial & final inquiries can be done with R itself, though:

```
bioc <- as.data.frame(available.packages(contrib.url("http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.8/bioc")))
cran <- as.data.frame(available.packages())

intersect(bioc$Package, cran$Package)
## [1] mixOmics
```